# Is ping the most effective way to find the best server?

Tags: node.js, server, geolocation, ping

I have multiple Node.js servers, and I want each client to connect to the one closest to them (or with the least hops).

At the moment, I'm am having the clients connect to the server which responds first (ie the lowest ping).

However, will this actually be an accurate way to match people up to the best server? If not, what would be a better method?

Answer (score 0):

A single ping will give you a single round-trip-time metric to go on. This is better than nothing and often (but not always) can be a good-enough proxy for general network latency to that server. It would be OK to start with this. Keep in mind that:

1. ping is an ICMP message which is typically handled by the OS directly not your application, so a pingable server might have a crashed or slow application
2. ICMP is commonly blocked by firewalls so an unpingable server may in fact be serving the application just fine.

---

However the "best" server is a lot more complicated, and if you want a high-quality determination of "best" you'll probably need to take into account the server's recent performance more holistically including things like recent application-level response times, total number of active connections, CPU load, I/O load, etc. You will probably want an application level way for the client to ask for basic health/performance metrics and the server to send them back and then an algorithm to convert that into a rankable numeric score. I would think a good next step after delay to get an empty response would be just to look at each server's average (or percentile) response time over the last minute or so and select the one with the lowest time.